# Can you pass camera through multiple widgets in Flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, camera

Is there any way to pass the CameraController between widgets in Flutter? My app requires the camera to be on multiple pages for the user to preview their recording and align objects. all the ways I have tried to pass the camera between pages has led to the application crashing on a physical device (i.e. initializing the camera on the first page and passing it between pages, creating a separate class for the camera to display the camera preview.)

Is there a Provider I can use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will make the `CameraController` `static` and when you are going to use it in another page you wil call it this way : `CameraController.class`

Comment: What do you mean by CameraController.class? Would it be something like controller: CameraController.class?

Comment: the class that you have implemented the controller